# State not update inside setInterval in React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a bot to auto generate text when component is mounted, but I have a problem when setInterval in useEffect. As my expected, I want to concate each word from the string in an sample text and update it into state until everything is done but my code not works, I only get a first word `Hello` in screen. What I am wrong and how I can resolve this problem?

```
const sampleText = 'Hello my customer, how can I help you?';

const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    let i = 0;

    const textToArray = sampleText.split(' '); 

    const newText = [...conversation];

    // create initialization state for the first time
    if (newText.length < 1) {
        newText.push({
            id: Math.random(),
            reply_as: 'bot',
            message: '',
        });
    }

    // begining to generate bot message to reply
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (i < textToArray.length) {
            // concate a message property in latest item with each string in newText array
            newText[newText.length - 1].message += textToArray[i];
            setConversation(newText);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

        i++;
    }, 300);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, []);

return (
   <div className="message-list">
      {conversation.map(item => (             
         <div>
            <span>Sender: {item.reply_as}</span>
            <p>{item.message}</p>
         </div>
      ))}
   </div>
)
```

Comment: It's impossible to know what you're actually showing without seeing the jsx.

Comment: @AntonPodolsky I updated jsx code in my question. Help me check it

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings at all on the browser console?  (At a glance I would expect at least two.)

Comment: @David i don't see any error, but I get an array object from console:

`[{ is: 0.7173462866218565 , reply_as: 'bot', message: 'Hello my customer, how can I help you?',
}]` even though I only see the word Hello appear on the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a new array reference, otherwise React doesn't re-render the component.

```
setConversation([...newText]);
```

The first `setConversation` triggered a re-render, that's why "Hello" was shown, but the following calls to `setConversation` didn't trigger a re-render because the array reference stayed the same.